# Eclipse Java Project built by Hudson misses Tomcat's libs

Tags: java, tomcat, hudson, jenkins, war

I have a Java Eclipse project, a webapp built for Tomcat. Under Project-->Properties-->Java Build Path--> Libraries I added the Apache Tomcat 7.0 libs, which reside on my system at C:\dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.14\lib ... on my system the project works perfectly fine.

BUT: I want to build the project using Hudson and Ant on a remote server. When the Hudson finds a change in the SVN, it checks out the project and tries to build and package it. Sadly, it cannot find the libs from Tomcat, which on the remote server are placed in C:\xampp\tomcat\lib. When I could find them, the built .war file is exported to yet another tomcat on another server, where the tomcat libs are placed in /opt/tomcat/lib.

How can I solve this issue?

Update: From my build.xml

```
<path id="Apache Tomcat v7.0 [Apache Tomcat v7.0].libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/annotations-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/catalina-ha.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/catalina-tribes.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/catalina.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/ecj-3.6.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/el-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/jasper-el.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/jasper.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/jsp-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../apache-tomcat-7.0.14/lib/tomcat-util.jar"/>
</path>
```

Comment: You say you added the tomcat libs to your build path in eclipse... But what about the ant script, are they added there, too?

Comment: Added the part of the build.xml

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is only a path problem (so ../../ is not always the parent directory of the tomcat installation). There are a few possibilities to solve that issue, two of them can be found here: [Hudson dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430252/hudson-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it this way:

I set the environment variable TOMCAT_HOME on my local system, on the Hudson's system and on the target server's system. Using the following build script let's ANT in Hudson compile the code correctly, so my .war get's built on the Hudson server.

```
<path id="Apache Tomcat v7.0 [Apache Tomcat v7.0].libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/annotations-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/catalina-ant.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/catalina-ha.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/catalina-tribes.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/catalina.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/ecj-3.6.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/el-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/jasper-el.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/jasper.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/jsp-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/servlet-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-api.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-coyote.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-dbcp.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-i18n-es.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${env.TOMCAT_HOME}/lib/tomcat-util.jar"/>
</path>
```

The only thing missing right now is that I publish the build's artifact (the .war file) on my target system with some integration plugin from Hudson.